# Words "configuration" and "settings" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, nouns, terminology

Are the words *configuration* and *settings* correct in the following context?:

*chair configuration* / *chair settings*

regarding the height of said chair, inclination of the chair back, etc.

If so, are they interchangeable or do they have a different connotation?

Answer (score 1):

*Configuration* is often used to describe the features and materials used in a finished product—in the case of a chair, things like ability to swivel, ability to recline, adjustable height, and adjustable back support, as well as option such as leather versus cloth upholstery, and metal versus plastic casters. "Settings" on the other hand typically refers to the adjustment options available within each feature included in a particular configuration.

The definitions of *configuration* and *setting* in Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) are somewhat ponderously expressed, but they contain the kernels of the distinction I laid out above:

> **configuration** *n* (1559) **1 a :** relative arrangement of parts or elements, as (1) : SHAPE (2) : contour of land {*configuration* of the mountains} (3) : functional arrangement {a small business computer system in its simplest *configuration*} **b :** something (as a figure, contour, pattern, or apparatus) that results from a particular arrangement of parts or components **c :** the stable structural makeup of a chemical compound esp. with reference to the space relations of the constituent atoms. **2 :** GESTALT {personality *configuration*}
>
> ...
>
> **setting** *n* (14c) **1 :** the manner, position, or direction in which something is set **2 :** the frame or bed in which a gem is set; *also* : a style of mounting **3 a :** the time place and circumstances in which something occurs or develops **b :** the time and place of the action of a literary, dramatic, or cinematic work **c :** the scenery used in a theatrical or film production **4 :** the music composed for a text (as a poem) **5 :** the articles of tableware for setting a place at table {two *settings* of sterling silver} **6 :** a batch of eggs for incubation

The common meaning of *configuration* in situations involving a complicated, multiple-option product, such as a fancy chair, is 1(b)—the apparatus that results from a particular arrangement of parts or components. This meaning is somewhat occluded by the overlapping meaning 1(a)(3)—the functional arrangement of parts or elements—which to me reads very much like an apt definition of *settings*; but the product-building sense of *configuration* refers to component arranging on a level that *settings* does not.

The relevant meaning of *settings* from the *Eleventh Collegiate*'s entry, meanwhile, is the first one: the manner, position, or direction in which something (in this case, a finished chair) is set.

Comment: I agree generally with this answer, but there is one thing that bothers me. In the question, the OP uses "chair configuration," which can easily mean "the way multiple chairs are arranged in a space." This is a 3rd meaning, at least for chairs: for elephants and cars, there is very little pull toward such an interpretation.

Comment: @Yorik: You're right—the meaning that you cite clearly applies to, for example, the layout of chairs in a room. My answer didn't address that possibility because it didn't match the particular context that the poster specified in the original question: "_chair configuration / chair settings_ regarding the height of said chair, inclination of the chair back, etc." Nevertheless, other visitors to this page may be interested in the spatial sense of _configuration_ that you refer to, and that meaning is well worth pointing out. I appreciate your clarification.